# remove with double-asterisk wildcards does not work

Tags: shell, wildcard

i have the following files under `test` directory

```
.
./test2
./test2/test_doc1.txt
./test2/test1
./test2/test1/test_doc2.txt
```

when I use `rm -rf test/**/test_doc2.txt`, it does not remove the files.
what is wrong?

Comment: What is the output of this command?

Comment: @xuhdev, silent. no message. and the file remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are using Bash.

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -rf test/**/test_doc2.txt
```

Add `shopt -s globstar` to your `~/.bashrc` file if you always want to enable this feature.

Comment: If you are on OSX, use `shopt -s extglob` the same way.